# Kotlin reflection to read members of a data class

Tags: kotlin

I have a config class MyConfig which has 4 different members of BackendConfig
BackendConfig has url, timeout and other members.

I want to filter any BackendConfig objects that have stage in their url.
I am using kotlin reflection to filter urls with word stage in them.

```
`fun MyConfig.getBackendConfigWithStg: List<String?> =
    apis::class.declaredMemberProperties.map {
    val backendConfig = it.getter.call(apis) as BackendConfig
    if (backendConfig.url.toHttpUrl().isStageUrl()) {
        apiConfig.url
    } else {
        null
    }
}`
```

This function throws the below error when running from hadoop's edge node.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:  kotlin.jvm.internal.ClassReference cannot be cast to  kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl at kotlin.reflect.full.KClasses.getDeclaredMemberProperties(KClasses.kt:162)`

Any pointers on how to solve this?

I am using Kotlin version 1.8 and kotlin-reflection jar of 1.8 version only.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: kotlin.jvm.internal.ClassReference cannot be cast to kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl
        at kotlin.reflect.full.KClasses.getDeclaredMemberProperties(KClasses.kt:162)